# no aspect invoked after method call

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I've got a bean `PlainDataSource` (in the external library) that extends `BeanNameAware`. In its method `setBeanName` it logs a message

```
Adding bean {} to container
```

I decided to write an aspect that would do couple of actions related to setting environment of `applicationContext` that happens after `setBeanName` method.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class DataSourceInitializerAspect {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @After("execution (* com.path.to.package.PlainDataSource.setBeanName(..))")
    public void initializeEnvironment() {
        LOGGER.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!! Invoking aspect !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        CustomPropertiesConfigurerExt propertiesConfigurer =
                applicationContext.getBean(CutsomPropertiesConfigurerExt.class);
        boolean localConfig = Boolean.parseBoolean(propertiesConfigurer.resolveProperty("localConfig"));
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = (ConfigurableEnvironment) applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        if (localConfig) {
            env.setActiveProfiles("local");
        } else {
            env.setActiveProfiles("server");
        }
    }
}
```

To `context.xml` I added

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

with corresponding namespaces

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
```

before

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

But when I start application I get the message

```
"Adding bean datasource to container"
```

but don't get `invoking aspect` message so I assume no aspect is being invoked. What's the problem?

Comment: There is no aspect at that moment yet. Those callbacks are done before Spring AOP has time to do its thing. Also what you want to do in your Aspect will not work, the `ApplicationContext` is already fully configured and up and running and setting the active profiles to something else won't make a difference.

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is that originally I used custom initializer `implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext>` but due to need of `applicationContext.refresh` it led to some issues with that `dataSource` bean. So I thought I could workaround it using aspect.

Comment: Why would you need a `refresh` in an `ApplicationContextInitialer`? You shouldn't do that...

Comment: @M.Deinum without it fails with error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via t
he ApplicationContext`

Comment: Because you shouldn't be accessing beans in an `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Those are executed before the `refresh` method is called so you can do additional configuration like setting active profiles. That is also the place to do it, anything else it too late in the process and will simply be ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum hm...then what to do? I want to set profile in dependence with property.

Comment: Find another way to read the property in an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see